# ElseIf statement error. VBA Macro to save to pdf

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I don't like the quality of my pdf if I print to PDF. But when I save to PDF it is much crisper. So I have tried this piece of VBA, but I keep getting errors on the ElseIf statements. What is actually wrong with it?

```
If Range("AE2").Value = 1 Then ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M55").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 2 Then ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M108").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 3 Then ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M162").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If
```

Thanks for looking into it all

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an underscore (line break) after the fourth line of code. Also you should break the line after `Then`. Try changing your code like:

```
If Range("AE2").Value = 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M55").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M108").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 3 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M162").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have now added the underscore. But now I am just getting the error: Compile Error: Else without if

Comment: I think you are missing some line breaks. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have got it now. Thanks for your help. Here is the code:

```
If Range("AE2").Value = 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M55").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 2 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M108").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 3 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M162").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

After refactoring, the code is much easier to read:

```
Dim exportRng As String

Select Case Range("AE2")
    Case 1
        exportRng = "A1:M55"

    Case 2
        exportRng = "A1:M108"

    Case 3
        exportRng = "A1:M162"

End Select

ActiveSheet.Range(exportRng).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "\" & Range("A23").Value & "\" & Range("AC6").Value & "\" & Range("AD6").Value & "\" & Range("AC3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```